# Issue with DAX query to sum a field in a table if another table has certain keys

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

Good Morning,

I'm creating a measure for a report and have run into a few issues. I've only been using DAX for about a month and aren't familiar with the nuances.

I have 3 tables that I'm working with.
tblSales
tblFactID
tblDIMID

The measure I'm trying to create is where if tblFactID[Key] NOT IN tblDIMID[Key] then SUM(tblSales[Sales]).

tblSales shares a key with tblFactID and tblFactID shares a key with tblDIMID, if any of that matters for this.

This is what I have in DAX Studio where I get "The expression specified in the query is not a valid table expression"

DEFINE
var a = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('tblDIMID'[Key], FILTER('tblDIMID', NOT('tblDIMID[Key] IN VALUES('tblFactID[Key]))))

EVALUATE
CALCULATE
(
SUM('tblSales'[Sales]),
FILTER('tblFactID, 'tblFactID'[Key] IN a)
)

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but my knowledge on the subject is limited.

I've been searching around for a few days and this is what I've come up with so far. I'm not familiar enough with the topic to know what I'm looking for to get this accomplished.

Comment: But what is your expression supposed to do in plain English?
Sounds like you need EXCEPT()

Comment: I need to check 1 table to see if it has a key from another table. If the two tables don't share a key then I sum a value from a third table.

Comment: COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE('RelatedTableName'))?
(the relationship would cause filtering to occur...) If you needed to force it, you could use FILTER() (which is an iterator function in disguise)

Comment: Do you have any relationships between any of the three tables?